# azure key-vault can't take multiple powershell scripts connecting to take secret value with

Tags: azure, powershell, adal, azure-keyvault

When executing single powershell script, i get credentials from my key vault,
or when i run them sequentialy ( on the same key vault secret).

But when i run scripts in parallel, where every one of them needs to to get the secret from the vault, i get following error :

```
(Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -vaultName $vault_name -Name $name).SecretValueText
```

"
Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret : user_interaction_required: One of two conditions was encountered: 1. The 
PromptBehavior.Never flag was passed, but the constraint could not be honored, because user interaction was required. 
2. An error occurred during a silent web authentication that prevented the http authentication flow from completing in 
a short enough time frame
"

I tried to sleep for a second and retry connection, but without much success.

Comment: Refer to this similar [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/5596#issuecomment-373536523) which proposed that RefreshToken expired and the error is being thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem was the thing number 2, silent web authentication that prevented the http authentication flow from completing.

Answer i had found is on the current  [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/4289).